# On click: activate a keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, onclick, key

So I'm looking for a work-around the whole blocking off opening local files from the browser. What I'm thinking is, I could have some script that, when it is activated, it initiates a set of keys that activate a shortcut that opens up the specific local file with that shortcut assigned.

I may be crazy, but is this possible?

Comment: You can dispatch keyboard events to the document, not the browser.

Comment: Well I don't really need it to be to the browser, I just need the computer itself to recognise the key presses which occur only when a button is clicked.

Comment: You missed the point. Javascript operates within a host environment, it only has access to the APIs that the host provides. In a browser, the browser is the host. It provides mostly DOM APIs with a very few others (XMLHttpRequest is one). You certainly can't send random keystrokes to the host system without the host providing an API. There isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible on the browser-side of things, which is what I'm assuming you're talking about?

The short answer is that browser shortcuts cannot be triggered through JavaScript.

You could try to directly navigate to the file in JavaScript by navigating to a `file://..../` path, though I'm almost certain that this is not permitted as it would be a huge security flaw in the browser.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I'm trying to work around. The site's on the local network so I'm not too worried about security since it's only being used here, but the browsers don't allow the direct opening.